# getting text from another activity using button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, get, android-edittext

how to get the text from edittext and paste into

```
URL url = url (et.getText (). getString ();
```

using button action on another activity, please help to fix the problem ?

Comment: It seems that you want use [activity for result](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult() and then onActivityResult() for the two activities to pass data
You may also store data in SharedPreference or a static field...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your editText's text through intent from FirstActivity to SecondActivity in which on button action you want to get that text.

In your A activity you can write -:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("URL",et.getText().toString());
intent.startActivity();
```

And in your SecondActivity on button action -:

```
newIntent.getStringExtra("URL");
```

I hope this helps.